# need a BETTER way for current location

Tags: android, networking, gps, location, locationmanager

Through nearly all problems/answers here and on the web, the best way for current location is as follows:

```
if ( mLocationManager==null )
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Location l;
for ( String provider : mLocationManager.getAllProviders() ){
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1, locationListener);
    l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if ( isBetterLocation(l, currentBestLocation) )
    currentBestLocation = l;
}
```

normally it works fine on Emulator and devices, but as noted by some guys, Android 4.0+ this code gives an [exception](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19857):

```
09-06 22:46:16.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(351): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network
09-06 22:46:16.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(351):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1325)
09-06 22:46:16.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(351):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1275)
09-06 22:46:16.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(351):     at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:646)
09-06 22:46:16.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(351):     at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:582)
09-06 22:46:16.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(351):     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:446)
```

But other apps on the same device can work properly when there IS only WIFI/3G coverage(GPS not working indoors).

So my question is:
How to retrieve current location inside a building?

PS: waiting for an Android image update is not acceptable, since other apps work properly on the same device. There MUST be a way to get the current location on the Android image with bug in LocationManager.

Kindest regards.

**EDIT:**

This time I tweaked my code as simple as possible(in the onResume):

```
    if ( mLocationManager==null )
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    for ( String provider : mLocationManager.getAllProviders() )
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

and in the locationListener.onLocationChanged:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (isBetterLocation(location, currentBestLocation)) {
        currentBestLocation = location;
        ...make use of this location
    }
}
```

Only **passive** and **gps** providers are available, **no network** provider can be obtained on my XT928, while on the other phone it shows up.

**EDIT 2**:
at last I achieved this by turning to a third-party library named as Baidu Location Library which also needs Access Key application. It works great.

Comment: Are you check google api versions supporting for android4.0?Please tell me what api u r using?

Comment: It's Android 4.4, Level 19. BTW I dont think it relates to this question. The app can run correctly on the Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
GoogleMap googleMap;

googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);//Inside on create()

May this help you!!!

Comment: I dont want to show a MapFragment/MapView for user. I just want to get the current location in the background without user interaction/notice, is GoogleMap still ok on this occasion?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call `mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 1, locationListener);` before `mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);`? As far as I know, `requestLocationUpdates` will register a listener that will keep notifying you of the phone's location. `getLastKnownLocation()` will give you the last known location for the provider. So the two are to accomplish different things.

If you just want one instance of the current location, get rid of `requestLocationUpdates()`. Then, you need to check if the current best location as per your code above is good enough. If it is not, you can request a single update later (outside your for loop): `locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, singleUpdatePI);`

Also note that you can only get location from the providers if the user has authorized so in the settings. In Android 4+, "Location access" settings explicitly request for authorization to:

> Let apps use Google's location service to estimate your location
>   faster.

Comment: On another Android device 4.1.1(Not Motorola, it's local brand), network provider works greatly with the same code. On my Motorola XT928, other apps can work correctly. So It's not the problem of the code or the Android OS image. There must be some Class/Method which can locate as expected without system update.

Comment: I have a code like I explained in my answer above that works great on a variety of devices. I think you are making conflicting requests that are affecting only some phones.

Comment: I edited my question, please help check it. I think it's not my programming problem. Would you share your code so that I can test it on my phone?

Comment: My code is adapted from here: https://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/. If you run the example app there on your device, does the problem persist?

Comment: Tried this code, no error occurs. But that's not the end: it takes quite a long time to locate indoors, and when there is only cellular coverage indoors, I cant wait till the location result shows.

Comment: It can take a long a time sometimes and there is nothing you can do about it except reduce the number of requests to update the location to a minimum. You just have to handle those cases when location is not available as best as you can.

Comment: Weird the coding environment becomes so rough for us. No clean way to tell my current location. The Bouncy Castle crypto library also reports NoSuchMethodError when run. Most of the time is consumed by such f*ck things, not by production.